# Stop 'Exchange Password Required' notification from appearing

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey, accounts, exchange

I keep getting a notification

> **Exchange Password Required**
> Enter your password for "emailaccount" in Internet Accounts.

in the top right of my screen and it doesn't disappear on its own. If I click its close button it will reappear within a few minutes.

I don't want to enter the password for this account, because on dodgy wifi or constantly changing internet connectivity situations, it will always log itself out again or cause some problem that makes this prompt return.

I just want to stop the prompt automatically appearing.

I will reenter the password when I feel the necessity to use that account again.

How do I stop this notification from appearing? How to ignore this status?

Comment: Have you tried Disabling the account? There's a checkbox in Mail Settings > Accounts.

Comment: @Ezekiel that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Stop Mail auto-fetching.

[image]

Image from Mojave, but it hasn't changed much since.

Comment: Can I change that for only this one mail account?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, it's global.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent Apple from automatically checking for mail from this account.

[image: Settings page]

Again, this is a printscreen from an older Mac version.  If you un-check that checkbox, then this account's mail would not be fetched automatically, but you can always fetch it by hand when you are ready for it.

Comment: This option does not exist in the most recent Mac version unfortunately

Comment: Ah, I see, all these "upgrades"...  No wonder Microsoft was charging people a "Downgrade Fee" when they wanted to have XP instead of Vista... :)